# Understanding promises in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m trying to understand promises in Angular. But I'm still mixing concepts. Please have a look at the following example in Angular 1.0.7:

```
// After locale is set code should be executed
initLocale(language).then(function (result) {               
    console.log("Insert code here");
});
```

Can someone can help me to understand why this code is working:

```
var initLocale = function(language) {
    return $translate.uses(language);
};
```

And this code is not:

```
var initLocale = function(language) {
    $translate.uses(language).then(function(result) {
        // I need to do things here! For example call another 
        // Asynchronous function.
        tmhDynamicLocale.set(language).then(function () {        
                console.log("Locale started!");                                                     
            });
        return result;                                                                      
    });
};
```

Comment: In the working example, initLocale is returning a promise. However, in the non-working example, initLocale is returning the result of that promise.

Comment: And how can I do to return the promise but executing the code inside?

Comment: In the non-working example, your `initLocale` function does not `return` anything itself.

Comment: Do you want `initLocale` to wait for `tmhDynamicLocale.set`?

Comment: @Rober, what about my explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$translate.uses(language)` returns Promise.

> I need to do things here! For example call another Asynchronous function.

If you want to resolve `results` after `tmhDynamicLocale.set(language)` - use Promise chain:

```
var initLocale = function(language) {

  var data = {}; 

   return  $translate.uses(language).then(function(result) {
       data.result = result;            
        return tmhDynamicLocale.set(language);
      }).then(function () {  
           // do your stuff here      
           return data.result;                                                               
        });                                                                                         
};
```

<kbd>[Simple Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hk7tqs7f/)</kbd>

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Yes, I've downvoted it because it's a bad practice (and as the linked topic explains, it doesn't even work for rejections). Just because the Angular docs don't list it as a bad practice doesn't mean that it's ok. Yes, one should not generically avoid deferreds, but one should avoid them *here*.

Comment: @Bergi ok got you, changed, tnx

Comment: Actually that doesn't work because `initLocale` itself doesn't `return` anything now. Btw, the `$q.when` is superfluous

Comment: Sorry guys, If I´m not wrong the code above is not working. @MaximShoustin

Comment: @Rober I fixed My response, also attached example where I use $timeout to simulate Promise

Comment: It works perfectly guys, except because there was a syntax duplicated }) that I removed. You are my heroes! Thanks! @MaximShoustin

Answer (score 1):

In the **first** example you've returned a `promise`.

In the second example you used `return` statement inside a `callback` function and that's a wrong thing.

The reason is that the `return result` line is executing before the `.set` **asynchronous** function is finished.

If you replace `return result;` with `console.log(result)`, you will see that you received **result** before `console.log("Locale started!")`;

Further more , `.then` method is used to handle the **result** of a `promise`, so you need to return a `promise` from you function.

Comment: No, the solution is not a callback function. The solution is to return a promise, not changing the signature of `initLocale`.

Comment: @Bergi, OP says `Can someone can help me to understand why this code is working and this code is not:`. My answer contains the correctly explanation why first works and second not.

Comment: @Bergi, I changed to `alternative solution`.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand either why you provided the correct explanation (even saying "*you need to return a promise from you function*") and then messed up the "solution" code.

Comment: I mean `another solution` as a alternative.

Comment: I'll upvote if you can also provide the code for the proper promise solution

Comment: @Bergi, Maxim Shoustin already gives the solution. I will only keep the explanation.